# Hard disk removal of partitioning

Tags: partitioning

I have a 4Tb hard disk (Western Digital), currently divided into 2 more or less equal partitions. Using Disk management, it does not show up in the top half of the graphic. Only in the bottom half where it shows up as Disk 1 on the left-hand side, and both partitions with a black bar at the top and "unallocated" on the right-hand side in the space below the top list of drives, in 2nd position after Disk 0 with 3 partitions for system reserve, C: and D:. 
The left-hand part I can expand, shrink or format (to not less than 1Tb or greater than about 2.5Tb) to a certain extent only, and format it. However, when clicking on the right hand part, I only get an option for "Properties" and "Help". All other options are greyed out.
Since I want to use the entire 4Tb for videos, I want to remove the partition to have undivided 4Tb (in reality about 3.7Tb max.).
How can I fix it. 
I have tried EaseUS with no success. I have also installed the h/d in my W10Pro desktop, with no more disk management functionality than in the W7U desktop.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the disk is currently using an [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partition table, which is only able to address up to 2TiB. This is why there are two "*halves*" both showing as unallocated.

To be able to use the full disk for partitions, you need to convert the disk to [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), as shown below:

[image: convert to GPT]

- Right click the left-hand "*header*" column of the disk
- Click "*Convert to GPT Disk*"

This should complete very quickly.

---

NOTE: Older operating systems are unable to use GPT disks, so it may be possible that this disk will not be accessible on older computers, TVs, etc...